# Higher order services in angular 5

Tags: angular, angular5, angular-services

Over the development of an angular 5 application I realized that I was repeating myself over the creation of services for accessing models through a REST api, so I figured it made sense to abstract them into the following factory:

```
import { Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { action, observable } from 'mobx-angular';
import { ObservableArray } from 'mobx/lib/types/observablearray';

interface Parameters {
  baseUrl: string;
  name: string;
}

export interface BaseModel {
  _id: string;
}

export interface RestCollectionServiceType<T> {
  items: ObservableArray<T>;
  get: () => Promise<void>;
  create: (T) => Promise<void>;
  remove: (T) => Promise<void>;
  update: (T) => Promise<void>;
}

export default <T extends BaseModel>({ baseUrl, name }: Parameters) => {
  class RestCollectionService {
    @observable
    items;

    constructor(@Inject(HttpClient) private http: HttpClient) {
      this.items = [];
    }

    @action
    async get() {
      const items = await this.http.get<T[]>(baseUrl)
        .toPromise();

      this.items.clear();
      this.items.push(...items);
    }

    // ...
    // Rest of the actions
    // ...
  }

  return RestCollectionService;
};
```

then one example service would be as follows:

```
import restCollectionServiceFactory, { RestCollectionServiceType, BaseModel } from '../utils/restCollectionServiceFactory';

export interface Team extends BaseModel {
  name: string;
}

export interface TeamsService extends RestCollectionServiceType<Team> {
}

export const TeamsService = restCollectionServiceFactory<Team>({
  baseUrl: '/api/teams',
  name: 'Team',
});
```

At the beginning I struggled a bit with DI as the decorator can only be used right before the class directive so I could not make any of my services (eg TeamsService) injectable but solved is by using the Inject decorator in the RestCollectionServiceType constructor, as the services have no other dependency to resolve it should be save not making them Injectables, just adding them into the providers array of the module should be enough for what I understood

```
...
import { TeamsService } from './services/teams.service';
...

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    ...
  ],
  imports: [
    ...
  ],
  providers: [
    ...
    TeamsService,
    ...
  ],
  bootstrap: [
    AppComponent,
  ],
})
export class AppModule { }
```

The thing is that this is working ok with ng serve but when I try to build I get the following error: `ERROR in : Can't resolve all parameters for TeamsAdminPageComponent in .../src/app/pages/admin/teams/teamsAdmin.page.ts: (?).`

being teamsAdmin.pate.ts the only component that depends on TeamsService

```
import {Component, Inject, OnInit} from '@angular/core';

import { TeamsService } from '../../../services/teams.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'rm-admin-teams',
  templateUrl: './teamsAdmin.page.html',
})
export class TeamsAdminPageComponent implements OnInit {
  columns = ['name', 'countryCode'];

  create = (team) => this.teamsService.create(team);

  remove = (team) => this.teamsService.remove(team);

  update = (team) => this.teamsService.update(team);

  constructor(@Inject(TeamsService) private teamsService: TeamsService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.teamsService.get();
  }
}
```

How could this be solved? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `TeamsService` probably needs to be a class instead of an interface, so the injector can create an instance of it. You also need to annotate the service with [`@Injectable()`](https://angular.io/api/core/Injectable), otherwise the injector will throw:

```ts
@Injectable()
export class TeamsService extends RestCollectionServiceType<Team> {
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response @rinukkusu, Initially I implemented the way you describe but it felt a bit of boilerplate having to provide the constructor of the extending class so that angular could inject the http dependency. I feel you should update your response and unless someone else provides a solution that doesn't require inheritance I will accept your response.

Comment: Did you check out the linked documentation for the `Injectable` annotation? I don't think there is a way around it, sadly .. :(

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I did yes and cannot find a workaround.